# Firebase gives exception when logging out

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Does any body know what the cause of this when I call try!

`FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()`

this happens
[image: error here]

**ANSWER**
when we call signout, the user uid becomes nil while the observer still needs to uid to remove the observer. Therefore to fix it I use addAuthStateDidChangeListener

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener({ (auth: FIRAuth,user: FIRUser?) in
                if user != nil {
                    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
                    controller.userID = (user?.uid)!
                    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
                }
                else {
                    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginRegisterViewController") as! LoginRegisterViewController
                    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
                }
            })
```

Comment: Is `User` nil? Put `print(user == nil)` before the line where your code breaks. See if `true` is printed to the console.

Comment: I have make sure that the user is not nill and I have tried using observeSingleEventOfType

so once I'm logged in, I will pull my user information from the database, the information has been displayed on my UI. so after that when I want to logout, the run time error occurs.

Comment: Great that you found the solution to your own problem. Can you post it as an answer? Self-answers are totally acceptable on StackOverflow and are more clearly tracked if they're a real answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**
when I go to this view, I will call the observer function, which I pass the (user?.uid)!. However when we log out, the (user?.uid)! will be nil while the observer still needs to call (user?.uid)!

**Solution**
Therefore to fix this, I created a variable called userID in that class and pass the (user?.uid)! to userID when I move to that view

here is the code to move to that view

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener({ (auth: FIRAuth,user: FIRUser?) in
            if user != nil {
                let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
                controller.userID = (user?.uid)!
                self.presentViewController(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginRegisterViewController") as! LoginRegisterViewController
                self.presentViewController(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        })
```